# Correct usage of Typescript Promise type in async/await methods

Tags: reactjs, typescript, async-await, react-redux

I am facing some difficulties when trying to destruct object that's being returned from THUNK async api call. The actual error is:

`Type '(dispatch: any, getState: any) => Promise<{ view: any[]; data: any[]; }>' has no property 'view' and no string index signature.`

thunk:

```
export const fetchSomething = ({
  arg1, arg2
}) => async (dispatch, getState): Promise<{ view: any[]; data: any[] }> => {
  const { data } = await someApiCall({
    arg1, arg2
  })

  const { view, data } = await JSON.parse(data)

  return {
    view,
    data
  }
}
```

inside react component:

```
const onSubmit = async (data) => {
  const { view } = await dispatch(fetchSomething(data))
//        ^
//        This is where error occurs
}
```

Can anyone help me understand what's wrong?

Comment: The `"thunk"` code you posted is incorrect. It's kinda impossible to see what you want to do. My best guess is that you are not returning anything from that function

Comment: I've edited the code to return `view` and `data`. Does that make sense now? How is the function incorrect?

Comment: The code LGTM, sth wrong with env? Is there a reproducible env somewhere for us to check?

Comment: According to [this .d.ts](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/blob/master/src/index.d.ts), the `dispatch` interface should've been extended by `redux-thunk` but it appears in your env that extension is not applied, which leaves the `dispatch` interface as the original one, thus the error you see.

Comment: FYI: I was able to get around that error by typing dispatch like: `dispatch<any>(fetchSomething(data))`. Lame but